# rails assets not being compiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, assets

I ran `rails server` and went to `http://localhost:3000`

I have
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>

in layout.html.erb

Here is application.css

```
 /*
  * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into  application.css, which will include all the files  
* listed below.   *   * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,  
* or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.   *   * You're  free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the   * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.  *   
*= require_self   
*= require_tree .  
*/
```

Isn't is suppsed to be compiled like

```
    <link href="/assets/twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
 <link href="/assets/twitter-bootstrap-static/fontawesome.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<link href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Something am I missing? I am using rails 3.2.8 I have

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
```

in application.rb

**UPDATE**

After I ran 
`RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

I can see compiled assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets are not ordinarily compiled in development mode:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development

That reference also has information on precompiling the assets if you want.

Comment: How do I change config to make it compile?

Comment: As noted in that reference: You can turn off debug mode by updating config/environments/development.rb to include:

config.assets.debug = false -- that will cause the assets to be compiled in debug mode.  You can also precompile the assets anytime you want, as noted here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: in that last comment, "that will cause the assets to be compiled in debug mode" should have read "that will cause the assets to be compiled in development mode"